# How do I calculate the time complexity of my method?

Tags: java, graph, time-complexity

I need to get something on this format:
C(N)=2C(N/2)+N
C(N)=O(N〖log〗_2 N)
But I don't understand how the values work because my method has a loop that normaly wont pass through all vertexs and a loop inside of it that normally goes all the way but the number of iterations varies a lot.

```
...

private static boolean bfs(int[] pathArray, int[] dist) {
        //Will make sure nodes are checked in the right order
        LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        //Starts the array dist[] that has the distance of the vertex to the 1st Critical point; and the array path[] that has the previous vertex;
        Arrays.fill(dist, -1);
        Arrays.fill(pathArray, -1);
        //Make CriticalPoint1 the starting point of the bfs
        dist[criticalPoint1] = 0;
        queue.add(criticalPoint1);
        int adj;
        int k;

        //Goes to all the adjacent vertexes and sees if any of them are the destination, if they are not adds them to the queue to check their adjacent vertexes
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            // k is the current vertex
            k = queue.remove();
            for (Graph.Edge<Integer> allAdjIterator : graph.getVertex(k).getAdjacencies()) {
                // adj is the current adjacent vertex
                adj = allAdjIterator.getIdAdj();
                if (dist[adj]==-1 && !allPassedEdges.contains(graph.getEdge(k,adj))) {
                    dist[adj] = dist[k] + 1;
                    pathArray[adj] = k;
                    queue.add(adj);
                    if (adj == criticalPoint2) { return true; }
                }
            }
        }
        //Critical points aren't connected
        return false;
    }

...
```

Comment: The recurrence relation you're giving here is for a recursive function. Your function isn't recursive (it's a BFS). Can you provide some more context here? Is there a reason you think you're supposed to get that particular recurrence?

Comment: That is just the template givent by the teacher, I only need the time complexity

Comment: I take it this is for an assignment? In that case, could you ask your teacher for a clarification?

Comment: The example was of a merge sort
public static void mergeSort(int[] table, int l, int r){
  if(l<r) {
   int mid = (l+r) / 2; 
   mergeSort(table,l,mid );  
   mergeSort(table, mid+1,right); 
   merge(table, left, right, mid); 
  }
 }
 C(N)=2C(N/2)+N (2.1)
 
C(N)=O(N〖log〗_2 N) (2.2)

2.1 is the cost and 2.2 is the result

Comment: OK that didnt work well, but for the first expression is the cost and the second the result

Comment: To clarify - is your question how to work out the time complexity of your code? Or how to apply the recurrence? Were you asked to apply the recurrence here?

Comment: Was just the time complexity